# Delete backward until met a char, like alt + bksp

Tags: bash, zsh

Say my current line was:

`/tmp/path/to/file:123`

Now I'm at the end of this line, now I want to delete `:123` by pressing some key combination, was that possible? (colon was merely mentioned as an example, it could be other chars, just wondering if I could bind keys to do that)

It's similar to what <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> does, but more specific on the word separator.

Bash or zsh are all welcomed.

Answer (score 5):

Search backward for `:`, then delete to the end of the line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `:` <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is the history search command, and the line you're editing is part of the history. Most commands, including <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, terminate the incremental history search and have their usual effect.

In vi mode: `F:C`

This applies in both bash and zsh (in the default configuration, I don't guarantee that there aren't exotic combinations of options in zsh that will make it react differently, and of course this assumes the default keybindings).

Comment: I didn't know the current line counted as part of the history — nice!

Answer (score 3):

In bash you can try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to start the `character-search-backward` function, then <kbd>:</kbd>. The cursor will then move to the ":" you can then type <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to kill to the end of the current word.
If you use this often you can create a binding for it in `~/.inputrc`.
These are readline functions and are documented in info: `info readline`.
I don't think there's a way to change `readline`'s idea of what a word is without hacking the source.

Comment: The answer @Giles gives is more elegant than mine: use `Ctrl` + `R` `:` to search.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and from what I've just tested on bash 3.2

alt+backspace and ESC+backspace will delete the word up to the first "strange" character.

ctrl+w will delete until the first space in encountered.

From what I understood you are not scripting it but doing while typing.

Answer (score 0):

In zsh, I can do this with the Emacs shortcuts. Your example above would be Alt-Backspace (or `M-DEL` in Emacs' lingo).

To do this, I have the following in `.zshrc`. (Note the URL -- I'm *not* taking credit for this!)

```
## emacs cursor-word movement (not identical but close enough)
#  also necessary for this:
#    /usr/share/zsh/functions/forward-word-match
#  (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847255 )
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash
```

The file mentioned looks like this:

```
emulate -L zsh
setopt extendedglob

local curcontext=":zle:$WIDGET" word
local -a matched_words
integer count=${NUMERIC:-1}

if (( count < 0 )); then
  (( NUMERIC = -count ))
  zle ${WIDGET/forward/backward}
  return
fi

while (( count-- )); do
  match-words-by-style
  # For some reason forward-word doesn't work like the other word
  # commands; it skips whitespace only after any matched word
  # characters.

  if [[ -n $matched_words[4] ]]; then
    # just skip the whitespace and the following word
    word=$matched_words[4]$matched_words[5]
  else
    # skip the word but not the trailing whitespace
    word=$matched_words[5]
  fi

  if [[ -n $word ]]; then
    (( CURSOR += ${#word} ))
  else
    return 1
  fi
done

return 0
```

Comment: Oh, I misread your question! Well, perhaps that code could be useful to you, anyway.